Trailer of car is too slow to catch up (Hinge Joint)
I am trying to add a trailer in my game and I want it to look as realistic as possible meaning that I want to use a Hinge Joint and not a Fixed Joint since a bit of movement is cool to see.
The issue is that the trailer takes a lot of time to catch up with the ConnectedBody as you can see from the video below:
Video on YouTube about the Trailer not correctly following the car
Is there a way to increase the Force of the Hinge Joint or it doesn't work for this kind of purpose? I can't find anything about this online.
I have tried:

Setting the trailerAttachPoint.solverIterations to 15 (seems to help)
Setting a low Brake Force and Brake Torque (helps a bit with the realism)
Setting the Hinge Joint Limits but the problem still occurs

It does still do some weird spins though, just like in the video above.
